# Analog current sensor design help needed

Tags: operational-amplifier, current-measurement, single-supply-op-amp

I have been thinking for some time about a circuit.  I have been a digital designer for most of my career, and have recently begun studying analog again, and find it a welcome challenge.  I am trying to design a simple current sensor to detect the presence of current flow in a 60Hz power line.  I don't need to measure the amount of current, just trigger an output once a threshold is passed (which I realize is like measuring, but above or below one value).

I started with the current sensing element as a transformer taken from a computer PSU that had a dedicated primary and secondary wrapped around a ferromagnetic core.  I tried to get deep into the engineering of the magnetics of this torroid, but was soon over my head.  Instead, I picked a random sample and began measuring around it:

[image]

To do this, I setup the below circuit, with the transformer inline with the hot lead of a standard US power plug, leading to an outlet, and the neutral straight through.  With simple devices (a laptop computer PSU, a small lamp, and a vacuum), I measured voltages on the secondary of the transformer anywhere from 1 to 7Vpp.
[image]

I then attached the secondary of the transformer across a resistor, the voltage of which is fed to the input of the below circuit (simulated by supply V1).

[image]

What I'm attempting to do here is use the diodes (which are Schottky) to limit/protect the first op amp, the lower one to clamp anything below ground to the ground of the circuits supply, and the upper one to clamp anything over Vcc to the positive supply.

The op amps are both LM324s using single ended 5V supplies.  I am using the first op amp to buffer/slightly amplify the current pulses in order to not attenuate them, which I'm then feeding to capacitor C3 to act as a tank that supplies voltage to the second op amp, which is setup as a comparator.  R6 is for discharge of C3.  Note that I only want the upper part of the incoming AC wave/pulses, and the lower diode nicely clips the lower part of them (below about 0.2V).  The thinking is that when there is enough current present, the voltage produced by op amp 1 and buffered in C3 will exceed the threshold of op amp 2, triggering its output (which I will eventually feed to a transistor to switch a relay).  I haven't thought too much about how to change the triggered level or build in any hysteresis, which would be nice.

I also realize, thanks to some awesome designers here, that an op amp must be biased.  R9 is an attempt to pull the non-inverting input to ground, but it did not yield expected results, because when I simulate, I still see that I am getting 1.4V out even with zero input, with many values of resistor there, so I'm guessing the diodes are forming a divider, and along with reverse leakage current from the first op amp, are preventing zero volts at the input even when no signal input is present.

My questions: Will the need to bias the op amp keep my attempt at sampling just the positive pulses from working?  Will what I'm attempting here even work at all?  Is there a better or simpler way to do what I'm attempting?  Are there any obvious problems with the circuit that you pros see that I don't?  What would you pro analog designers do to achieve this?  I know a lot of times on this board, someone asks a question about how they can do A using only components X,Y,and Z, and that's not the case here.  I'm completely open to alternative ways of doing this.  Can anyone point me to any circuits made for this purpose?

Before it's suggested that I use something simple like an ACS712 current sensing module, I know they exist, but I'd like to use as many first principles as possible to design this in a mostly analog way.  I understand, thanks to some veterans, how this board works, so I will gladly accept an answer, but don't get worried if I don't right away.  And please, I realize we have many experts in our midst, but to the extent you are able and willing, explain it to me like I'm 5.  Thank you for your help, and please do me a favor and don't slap me around like an old pot roast for not remembering something from school.  I've been designing large scale systems for decades and am just trying to get back into analog.

Comment: Without having fully read your post (major apologies!), I'd say you could do it easily with: a transformer as you have, then a rectifier, and a voltage-reference-cum-comparator, which is a cheap commodity part.

Comment: You can buy a cheap current transformer on Ali (SCT, YHDC,,. similar devices under 2$), you put two diodes in anti-parallel and comparator. Your circuit is way too complex (expensive) for you needs.

Comment: If you are rectifying _and_ using op amps, a [precision rectifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_rectifier) is probably the topology to use.

Comment: The critical term here is ‘current transformer’. Usually you would pass either the hot or neutral wire through the core rather than through a winding. You then have a low value ‘burden’ resistor on the secondary. Google ‘current transformer’ for heaps of references.